# python/xbmc scraping embedded video url

Tags: android, python, xbmc, kodi

I have been trying hard to scrape movierulz.sz website and I could get the embed url finally but could not get it played in kodi. Here is the example.

http://www.movierulz.sx/blood-circus-2017-hdrip-full-movie-watch-online-free/

from that i took the first openload source, which routes to http://embedscr.to/?p=39458

And this inturn goes to https://openload.co/embed/qOH7Lgjwdmk/ (I could play this in IE or Chrome)

if I give this link to KODI, I get below error.  Please help with this.

> 00:07:28.852 T:3640  NOTICE: VideoPlayer: Opening:
>   https://openload.co/embed/qOH7Lgjwdmk/ 00:07:28.852 T:3640 WARNING:
>   CDVDMessageQueue(player)::Put MSGQ_NOT_INITIALIZED 00:07:29.016 T:9360
>   NOTICE: Creating InputStream 00:07:29.491 T:9360  NOTICE: Creating
>   Demuxer 00:07:29.656 T:9360   ERROR: CDVDDemuxFFmpeg::Open - error
>   probing input format, https://openload.co/embed/qOH7Lgjwdmk/
>   00:07:29.656 T:9360   ERROR: CVideoPlayer::OpenDemuxStream - Error
>   creating demuxer 00:07:29.656 T:9360  NOTICE: CVideoPlayer::OnExit()

Also when i tried using URL resolver, i am getting below error.

Code I added:

hmf = urlresolver.HostedMediaFile(url=url) xbmcgui.Dialog().ok("url",str(hmf.resolve().msg))

Err Msg:

Decode-O Parsing Failure: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'group'

Err Log:

21:14:53.320 T:2296 NOTICE: URLResolver: Initializing URLResolver version: 2.10.0 21:14:53.721 T:2296 NOTICE: URLResolver: No Settings Update Needed 21:14:54.074 T:2296 ERROR: URLResolver: Resolver Error: Decode-O Parsing Failure: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' - openload - https://openload.co/embed/qOH7Lgjwdmk

Comment: Try to play your url using url-resolver module and you will able to stream in Kodi

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I did try the URL Resolver and update the error i am getting in my question.  Could you please suggest.

Comment: Please mention the exact URL you want to play in Kodi so I can give you the accurate solution